# Combining a CASE WHEN statement & a column containing strings of type "Column 1 || '_' || Column 2" in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table consisting of three columns, which are called the following:

1) Month
2) Store_Type
3) City

I need this table to be expanded to contain five columns and the two columns that I wish to be added are detailed below.

Firstly, the query needs to create a new column called Store_Code. The Store_Code columns job is to store a numerical value which corresponds to what type of store it is.

I presume this would done using a CASE WHEN statement of the type:

```
SELECT Month,Store_Type,City,
CASE
WHEN Store_Type = 'Corner Shop' THEN '1'
WHEN Store_Type = 'Megastore' THEN '2'
WHEN Store_Type = 'Petrol Station' THEN '3'
....
ELSE '10'
END Store_Code
FROM My_Table
```

After this is complete, I need to create a column known as "Store_Key". The values contained within the Store_Key column need to be of the following form:

"The Month For That Row"*"The Store Type For That Row"*"The City associated with that row"_"The Store Code for that row"

I imagine the best way to create this column would be to use a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT (My_Table.Month || '_' || My_Table.Store_Type || '_' || My_Table.City || '_' || 
My_Table.Store_Code)
FROM My_Table
```

What I need is for these two separate queries to be combined into one query. I imagine this could be done by sub-setting the different SELECT queries but I am open to and grateful for any alternative solutions.

Thank you for taking the time to read through this problem and all solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to write a select query or attempting to populate the new columns? You're 95% of the way there if you want to update.

Comment: @ZynonPutneyII I am only trying to update this table at the moment, in accordance with the column rules as defined in the question. Not too interested in adding new values to it, at the moment.

Comment: If you're updating the table with those rules, then you don't need a select statement at all, per my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Do the `case` *expression* part inside a *derived table* (the subquery):

```
SELECT (My_Table2.Month || '_' || My_Table2.Store_Type || '_' || My_Table2.City || '_' || 
My_Table2.Store_Code)
FROM
(
    SELECT Month,Store_Type,City,
    CASE
    WHEN Store_Type = 'Corner Shop' THEN '1'
    WHEN Store_Type = 'Megastore' THEN '2'
    WHEN Store_Type = 'Petrol Station' THEN '3'
    ....
    ELSE '10'
    END Store_Code
    FROM My_Table
) My_Table2
```

Comment: With a slight modification to ensure the name of the final column was correct, this appears to have worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this is you trying to populate your new columns, then you need an update statement. I would use two updates to ensure you get the store_case committed for your store_code. Otherwise if you're deriving it in real time, the subquery select answer would be the way to go.

```
update my_table
set store_case = 
  case store_type 
    when 'Corner Shop' then 1 
    when 'Megastore' THEN 2
    when 'Petrol Station' THEN 3
    ...
    else 10
  end case;

  commit;

update my_table
set store_code = Month || '_' || to_char(Store_Type) || '_' || City || '_' || Store_Code;
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to use sub query? It can be done within single query as following:

```
SELECT My_Table.Month || '_' || My_Table.Store_Type || '_' || My_Table.City || '_' || 
      CASE
          WHEN Store_Type = 'Corner Shop' THEN '1'
          WHEN Store_Type = 'Megastore' THEN '2'
          WHEN Store_Type = 'Petrol Station' THEN '3'
          ....
          ELSE '10'
      END as result
FROM My_Table
```

or you can use `DECODE` function as following:

```
SELECT My_Table.Month || '_' || My_Table.Store_Type || '_' || My_Table.City || '_' || 
       DECODE(Store_Type,
             'Corner Shop', '1', 
             'Megastore', '2', 
             'Petrol Station', '3' 
              ...., 
             '10') -- this is default value same as else part of the case statement
              as result
FROM My_Table
```

Cheers!!